# ArcGIS online web app with proxy

Tags: arcgis

I have ArcGIS online private web applications that I whould like to share inside an closed intranet network.

As our main map builder is not code oriented, we whould like to use the provided webappviewer in arcgis online. My idea was to use the proxy approach (https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy)
and control the access to the site using a proxy where users whould be authenticated using Windows before forwarding the request.

However when accessing the url of the web-app with the proxy it fails in loading the static files of the webappviewer (css and js) as they try to load from the proxy host return 404 not found.

Has anyone had a similar issue and found a suitable solution ?